# creating unit testing using makefile

Tags: c, unit-testing, makefile

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

I am wondering does any one know of any tutorials or text books that cover using makefile to create some simple unit testing for my c programs.

I would like to run some automated testing that will create a test suite and add this to my Makefile.

Just want some ideas on how to get started.

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to generate testing stubs based on the functions of your program? Or do you want to add a test target to your Makefile?

Comment: In the latter case (add a test target) [ct](https://github.com/kr/ct) a.k.a. (Relatively) Easy Unit Testing in C, is your friend.

Comment: @evnu I would like to add both if I could. Do you know of any websites  or test books that have examples of this? Thanks.

Comment: Implementing a script to create stub functions (including a message `printf("not implemented")`) is straight forward: create an xml representation `output.xml` of the source coude using `gccxml`, use `nm` to extract the symbol names of the text code section, get the corresponding symbols from `output.xml` to ensure that they are functions, and write the stubs to a file. Adding a test target to the makefile is no different than adding other targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generating Test Function Snippets

Generating function snippets is easy with the help of `gccxml` and `nm`. The following bash script `generate_snippets.sh` can  be called with one command line argument to generate a test function snippet for each function defined in a source file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Generate stub functions for one file
#

# # Initialize
FILE=$1

[ ! -e "$FILE" ] && echo "file doesn't exist" && exit -1

# # Compile
OBJECT=$(mktemp)
gcc -c $FILE -o $OBJECT

# # Get Functions

# ## Get all symbols in the text sections
Y=$(mktemp)
nm $OBJECT | grep " T " | awk '{print $3;}' | sort > $Y

# ## Get functions defined in the file (including #includes)
# get all functions defined in the compilation unit of $FILE, excluding included
# dynamically linked functions

XML=$(mktemp)
X=$(mktemp)
gccxml $FILE -fxml=$XML
grep "<Function" $XML | sed 's/^.*name="\([^"]*\).*/\1/g' | sort > $X

# ## get the common lines
# This is done to get those functions which are defined in the source file and end up in
# the compiled object file.
COMMON=$(comm $Y $X -1 -2)

# # Create stubs
for func in $COMMON;
do
    cat <<_
// Test stub for $func. Returns 1 if it fails.
char test_$func() {
    return 1;
}
_

done

# # Clean up

rm $OBJECT $XML $X $Y
```

#### TODOS

The script is not yet perfect. You should probably include a test to only generate test functions for those functions which aren't tested yet. As this is done analogous to finding the common names between `$X` and `$Y`, I leave this as an exercise. When this is implemented, it makes sense to run this script from a Makefile. See the other answer for pointers on that.

### Example Usage

Consider the C file `hello.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo();
int bar();

int main() {
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}


int foo() {
    printf("nothing\n");
    return 1;
}

int bar() {
    printf("still nothing\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Running the script above with this file as input yields the following output:

```
// Test stub for bar. Returns 1 if it fails.
char test_bar() {
    return 1;
}
// Test stub for foo. Returns 1 if it fails.
char test_foo() {
    return 1;
}
// Test stub for main. Returns 1 if it fails.
char test_main() {
    return 1;
}
```

Just put those snippets into the appropriate file and fill them with logic as needed. After that, compile the test suite and run it.

Comment: Thanks for completing the answer.

Comment: Please note that the script above does not use `CFLAGS`, which might be a good addition if you are using macros to include/exclude source code. Otherwise, the `nm` hack might not work as intended.

Answer (score 11):

Yes indeed, less than 30 lines of  [makefile](/questions/tagged/makefile) you can build a generic unit test engine.

Note that I wrote the following for testing [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) and [lisp](/questions/tagged/lisp) scripts but it can be easily customized for [c](/questions/tagged/c). Actually, IMHO, the whole thing is a nice example of the power of [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) scripting.

To begin,  you place all your tests is executable files in some `$Testdir`. In this example, all the tests have file names `001` `002`, etc (with no extension).

Next, you need some set up stuff:

```
Here=$(PWD)
Testdir=$(Here)/eg
ready:  $(Testdir) $(Tmp)
$(Tmp) :
        @ - [ ! -d $(Tmp) ] && mkdir $(Tmp)
```

Then you'll need to collect all the tests into a list called `$Tests`

```
Tests:=$(shell cd $(Testdir); ls  | egrep '^[0-9]+$$' | sort -n  )
```

(Note the use of `:=`. The is a slight optimization that builds `$Tests` once, and uses it many times.)

Each file `$(X)` in my list of `$Tests` can be executed in two ways. Firstly, you can just `run` it. Secondly, you can run it and `cache` the results in `$(X).want`.

```
run : ready $(Testdir)/$(X)
        @echo $X 2>&1
        @cat $(Testdir)/$(X) | $(Run)  

cache : ready
       @$(MAKE) run | tee $(Testdir)/$X.want
       @echo new test result cached to $(Testdir)/$X.want
```

I `cache` a test outcome once the test is ready to go and is producing the right output.

The actual execution is defined by a magic variable called `$(Run)`. This is something you have to write specifically for the language being tested. For the record, I'm testing Gawk scripts so my `$(Run)` is just as follows (and you can change it to whatever you need).

```
Run= gawk -f mycode.awk
```

Once that is done, then to run one test, I just compare what I get after running `$(X)` to the cached copy:

```
test : ready $(Testdir)/$(X).want
      @$(MAKE) run > $(Tmp)/$X.got 
      @if diff -s $(Tmp)/$X.got $(Testdir)/$X.want > /dev/null;  \
        then echo PASSED $X ; \
        else echo FAILED $X,  got $(Tmp)/$X.got; \
        fi
```

This is how I run all  my tests:

```
tests:;  @$(foreach x, $(Tests), $(MAKE) X=$x test;)
```

You can also do a batch cache of all the current outputs (warning: do not do this unless your tests are currently generating the right output):

```
cache :
        @$(foreach x, $(Tests), $(MAKE) X=$x cache;)
```

Finally, if you want, you can also get final score of the PASSEDs and FAILEDs:

```
score :
       @$(MAKE) tests | cut -d\  -f 1 | egrep '(PASSED|FAILED)' | sort | uniq -c
```

That's it: as promised- a generic unit tool in Make in under 30 lines. Share and enjoy.

Comment: +1, very neat. The answer doesn't contain the other part of the question (generating stub functions from C source code), but it's a nice answer nevertheless.

Comment: My bad- I don't use "C" but I script in a dozen or so languages. 

The above Makefile lets me handle them all with the one test engine. (cavat: the $(RUN) variable must be tuned per language).